# About CDN. Where do the methods work? Client? Sever?

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, cdn

I am Japanese and not good at English sorry.

I was looking at this doc.

https://developers.google.com/docs/api/quickstart/js

```
<script async="" defer="" onload="this.onload=function(){};handleClientLoad()" onreadystatechange="if (this.readyState === 'complete') this.onload()" src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
```

I thought we can't use google api on client side.

Because it needs server such as node.

But in this way we can use gapi() method only in client side.

Is that mean method from CDN works on server?

Not client side?

Comment: Client side. Cdn delivers script. Script is executed client side.

Comment: I think that @TheMaster 's comment is correct. As one more additional information, when you test [the quickstart of Javascript](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/quickstart/js), the script doesn't work even when you directly put the HTML of quickstart to your browser. It is required to load the HTML from a web server. Please be careful this. At the official document, python is used as the web server. In this case, the HTML and Javascript are loaded from the web server and CDN. But that is run at the client side.

Comment: @Tanaike

Thank you so much for teaching me. I am wondering if this is working on client side, why there is no npm module for this? Why do you think there is only CDN?

Comment: Although, unfortunately, I cannot understand the result you want, I think that those depend on the service provider which is Google side. How do you think about this?

Comment: Sorry I want to use google api only by client side. And I want to use it as a library in client side. Like, I want to import it like `import gapi from 'google-api'` and use it. But I  think we can only use CDN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Briefly:**
The Content Delivery Network, *delivers* the script to the client. Then all methods from that library run on the client side.

---

**More verbose:**
When you request a website from your browser, it executes your code on your side (Client), when it gets to a line where it needs to fetch some *content* from a CDN, it makes the request to the CDN (*network of servers*) and receives what the CDN *delivers*. The received source, if called in any subsequent lines will be executed in your browser (Client-side)

Comment: Thank you so much. I am now wondering why there is no node_module for this. There is module for server side node, but none for client. Is it impossible to import on client side like this? `import gapi from 'google-api'` Does it have to be CDN?

Comment: The difference is that when you are using Node, you are the server. You are serving the application, and node understands that you are looking to import a library which has been installed with the package manager npm. But the browser does not share the environment with npm

Comment: Thank you so much. I know that, but I am wondering is it impossible that the library become a part of npm registry? Does it have to be CDN?

Comment: You should ask that as a new question and use the tag nodejs.